# Python: difference between "|" and "or" in equation

Tags: python

all.
I'm running a simple python program and I found when I use `followees = self.followee.get(userId, set()) | set([userId])`, it passed the test. However, if I use `followees = self.followee.get(userId, set()) or set([userId])`, it didn't.

So, apparently, there are some differences between these two operators in equations. Does anyone have some idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: `|` is the union operation for sets.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ oh, I see. It doesn't mention that in the python documentation. It just says l is like OR operator :(. Does l means union for dict too? List?

Comment: `|` is the bit-wise OR (for `set` it acts as union) and `or` is the logical OR.

Comment: @ztlevi they define an `__or__` implementation for sets, which is called when you do set 1 | set 2, it's actually set 1.__or__(set 2)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ so it's not for "or", just l?

Comment: Indeed. `or` and `and` are just truth value comparers. I'm not 100% sure on this one, but arithmetic operators can be overloaded for classes.

Answer (score 5):

For sets (which are your operands here), `|` returns the union of both sets (the operands), while the `or` operator returns the first *truthy* operand (a non-empty set) or the last, if all of the operands are *falsy* — making `or` a short-circuit operator.

Consider the following examples:

```
>>> set([1,2,3]) | set([4])
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> set([1,2,3]) or set([4])
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> set([1,2,3]) or set([])
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> set([1,2,3]) | set([])
set([1, 2, 3])
```

<sub>Notice that with two operands, if at least one of the operands is *falsy*, both `|` and `or` give the same results.</sub>

[`or`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)'s behaviour is consistent for all objects, while `|` would behave differently depending on how the operands implement the [`__or__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__) or [`__ror__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ror__) magic methods e.g. acts as the bitwise *or* for integer types and *[max-]union* for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects.

Comment: it is also like `bitwise or` with integers, correct